# using sscanf to read fixed length strings

Tags: php, scanf

I'm trying to `sscanf` to read a bunch of successive fixed length strings but it's not working very well. I can print a fixed length string thusly:

```
sprintf('%.5s', 'aaaaabbbbb');
```

But if I try to use `%.5s` to read a fixed length string (eg. the first 5 bytes of an input string) it doesn't work. eg.

```
var_dump(sscanf('aaaaabbbbb', '%.5s'));
```

If I do that `var_dump` returns `NULL` and I get the following Warning:

```
Warning: sscanf(): Bad scan conversion character "."
```

I tried `%5s` in addition to `%.5s` but that doesn't work as desired either. eg.

```
var_dump(sscanf('aa aabbbbb', '%5s'));
```

That returns this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "aa"
}
```

What I'd want it to return is this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "aa aa"
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that any space character is considered as a new input using `%s`.

According to [sscanf](//php.net/sscanf) comment, this should work :

```
$result = sscanf("  Vendor: My Vendo Model: Super Model Foo  Rev: 1234", 
             '  Vendor: %8[ -~] Model: %16[ -~] Rev: %4c',
             $vendor, $model, $rev);
```

So, in your case :

```
var_dump(sscanf('aa aabbbbb', '%5[ -~]'));
```

It works fine on PHP 5.2.10.